# SSH Key authentication on WSL always says 'debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method'

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, key-authentication, windows-subsystem-for-linux

`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` looks like this: [pastebin.ubuntu.com link](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zdqtv8tFF3/). It's default except I uncommented authorized keys, pubkey auth and listenaddress.

Then I did `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 user@host`, after that I can see that `authorized_keys` file is there and is correct. Then I restarted `sshd` with `--full-restart` key. After which I always get the following when trying to connect:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: ED25519 SHA256:Te7bTBJr1zQqeagqlCYl6Vsc19UF1qc67dSRRfBJ6J0 /home/jus/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jus/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/jus/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jus/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/jus/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jus/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/jus/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
justas@192.168.56.1's password:
```

If I disable password authentication, I just get permission denied straight away. And I never get asked to enter a passphrase for the key.

To test I've done exactly the same steps for sshd on the virtual machine (Xubuntu), and it all worked OK. I used the same key, and I can connect from WSL ssh client just fine.

Comment: What do the SSH logs say?

Comment: There are no /var/log/auth.log on WSL machine. Also no auth.log was found by find search.